# Texture problem with Makehuman model in blender

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor

I am using a Makehuman model in blender, and rendering with cycles. As shown in the images below, I have used these nodes to put the texture of the tshirt on the person. There is a black spot on arm. What is the problem, how do I get rid of the black part?

[image: Nodes]

result of texturing in blender
[image: result of texture in blender]

textured model in makehuman
[image: image in makehuman]

Comment: Adding a blend file could help.

Comment: @Vitaliy, here is my work .blend http://www.pasteall.org/blend/35315

Comment: @Vitaliy here is the texture files that I have used with the human http://www.filedropper.com/textures

Comment: well... as I thought your UV's are completely off.

Comment: @Vitaliy, What do you mean by UV's are completely off and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 3):

UV map is a coordinate system that helps to wrap a 2D image around your 3D object.
You can read a little about UV's here http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/UV_Map_Basics

Here is your situation.

[image]

What you see in white is your texture, exported from Make Human. The wires you see are your UV map. To look good they must match. I don't know how you ended up with sweeter when your character in Make Human had T-shirt, but I think this is your problem.

To fix it you need 1 of 2. Either edit your UV's to match the texture or edit your texture to match the UV's. You can read about the first way in the link I gave you, and you can edit the 2nd in any image editing software.